# Get updated data from view within transaction jpa hibernate spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, transactions

I have a new requirement in my application: I need to fetch some data from the view and post it to a 3rd party web service.

Unfortunately I cannot share any code here because it is proprietary and I have no right to exchange any piece of code from the organization I am working for.

It's SOA, and when I make a payment in the system, an observer pattern is initiated with a service which loads my listener class, before posting to a 3rd party, data is stored in the DB by using a different number of DAO classes, which start transactions and store data to the db. From these table my view is updated.

I guess hibernate keeps the data cached and it doesn't get flushed until the whole service execution is not completed. When I land on my service which is called within the same transaction/service context (spring managed), the view data is not updated and its locked for that time, I cannot get the data and it got stuck there. If I manually commit the transaction, it causes inconsistency with data as other DAO's also called there commit, in that case the view did not got updated , I could also get data out of it, as our application is using AOP, but it causes a exception, because I have manually committed my transaction (which by architecture I think is not allowed).

I am quite new to all of this, I did tried flush, Transactional annotation with propagation for new transaction but nothing. If ay would give me a hint what to do, that would be helpful.

Any solution out of JPA or Hibernate can be applied as i can use any of these.

Comment: It is hard answer your question because it is quite complicate to understand. Anyway I would recommend you that you spend some time in understanding what `EntityManager.flush` does (and when hibernate flush its data) as well as understand what transaction isolation levels are.

Comment: Thanks for the reply ralph. i did tried flush and transaction isolation (jpa does not support custom level isolations). But it didnot worked out,

Comment: But your database use a isolation level, this is typically defined in your JDBC-Connection configuration.